# How an app can find out that windows startup is complete

Tags: windows

I have a windows application which gets launched at windows startup. In the application i dont want to do anything until windows start up is complete.

So is there any way i can register for any event which indicates that windows start is complete. My main aim is to find out through my app when the windows start up is complete.

Comment: What specifically does "windows startup complete" mean to your application? Are you waiting on certain other auto-started programs to finish?

Comment: Yes exactly i am waiting on certain other auto-started program to finish. Basically i have to find out that whether another program was started during windows startup or not. If it is not that then i have to start that program through my app. So i thought a clearn approch will be to let windows start up to complete, then find the auto-start program was launched or not and do the needful

Comment: Is the "other auto-started program" your own, that you can modify, or a third party?

Comment: "other auto-started program" is a third party program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan here "auto started programs to finish" just means that they were launched during windows start up. Here "Finish" does not mean the auto started program has been closed.

Comment: I have accepted some answers.... it was due to my ignorance that i was not aware about it and answers were not getting accepted.

Comment: Can you tell us what the third-party program is? And which version of Windows?

Comment: Third party program is Microsoft Lync 2010 and windows version is Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: @azhrei - I have provided answers to your questions. Please provide your further comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically i have to find out that whether another program was
> started during windows startup or not. If it is not that then
> i have to start that program through my app.
>
> ...
>
> Third party program is Microsoft Lync 2010

In that case, your program can just launch Lync.

---

DETAILS

If you run Lync when it is already running, the first Lync comes to the foreground. (The second Lync exits).

So, if your program is autostarting it doesn't matter whether it runs before or after the Lync autostart. And it doesn't matter if Lync is not configured to autostart or not.

Scenario A:

1. Lync is configured to autostart
2. Autostart runs Lync
3. Your Program tries to run Lync, but the Autostart one will continue

Scenario B:

1. Lync is configured to autostart
2. Your Program runs Lync
3. Autostart tries to runs Lync, but your Program one will continue

Scenario C:

1. Lync is not configured to autostart
2. Your program runs Lync

Finally, if Lync starts and then exits, the second invocation will simpy launch Lync again, which also fulfils your requirements.